# Cannot send TempData back to same view after Ajax Post action in .NET 6

Tags: ajax, razor, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-6.0

Fair warning, I lack the fundamental understanding of how controllers work and reading about them for hours doesn't seem to help. This is probably terrible design. However, all I want to accomplish seems like it should be fairly simple, but I have not made any progress.

Setup is VS 2022 with basic ASP.NET Core 6 MVC web app and EF Core 6.

Every feature of this application will be on a single static page, using a single form.

What I need is the form to auto-populate readonly input fields on text update so the user has confirmation they scanned the right product into the app, these will also be submitted with the form's final post.

All functionality works up to the point where the user entered field sends value back to the home controller on update and the controller performs the query to find the correct values. It breaks when the http `POST` action tries to send this data back to the view.

I've tried many methods of getting value back, but cant get it to read client side. `TempData` appears to work so I can see it with C# code in the view, but not modify existing client markup.

Here are my relevant controller pieces

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult GetItem(string value)
{
    //item is assigned single string value from db
    item = //dbquery

    TempData["Message"] = item;

    // Tried changing this to a few different return types but nothing seems to change
    return View("Index");
}
```

The models are all auto-generated files from scaffolding and work great

In the view, I temporarily have all the js logic that sends the data back. I am only using ajax because it was the only way I could find to get real time data back to the controller without using a form/button post. The ajax call does open the right controller action and sends the right data to it, but I cannot find a way to read the new `TempData` value from the controller back to the view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function SendInput(sn) {   
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '@Url.Action("GetItem")',
                    data: { inputID: sn.target.value },
                    dataType: "text",
                });
                
                @{
                // tempval here does get assigned the proper item
                var tempval = TempData["Message"];
                if (tempval != null) 
                    {
                        //this code never generates or updates data on the view
                        @:var temp = @tempval.ToString();
                        @:$('#item').val(temp);
                    }
                }     
        }

        const serial = document.getElementById('InputID');
        serial.addEventListener('input', SendInput);         
</script>
```

Edit: adding the rest of the HTML

```
@using ScanForm.Models;
// temp table for form submission. This page will eventually read and write to many tables
@model InvItem


@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Scan Form";
}

// Form submit controller not implemented yet
<div>
    <form method="POST" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Add">
        <div class="row w-50 form-group">
            <div class="col mb-3">
                <label class="col-form-label" asp-for="InputID">Serial #</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="InputID" asp-for="InputID">
                <small id="" class="form-text text-muted"></small>
            </div>
            <div class="col mb-3">
                <label class="col-form-label" asp-for="Model">Item</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="item" readonly>
                <small id="" class="form-text text-muted"></small>
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you share your full html code? So that we can reproduce your problem.

Comment: Theres not much else, it's just a basic form. Most of this project is auto-generated and still in its early vanilla stages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult GetItem(string value)
{
    //item is assigned single string value from db
    item = //dbquery

   return Json(item);
}
```

Then add success: function in your ajax code like:

```
 $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '@Url.Action("GetItem")',
                    data: { inputID: sn.target.value },
                    dataType: "text",
                    success: function (temp) {
                             $('#item').val(temp);
                             }
                });
```

Comment: Oh my, I could not understand how the controller returns things, but this helped me make sense of it a lot more. Much cleaner and simple and does exactly what I was trying to accomplish. Thank you!

Now to go back and learn how to do all the project logic in the proper MVC way...

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to MVC & Razor, it can be a bit of a challenge to get your head around what is happening but once you get the pieces in order it does start to make sense. :)

Razor code is view engine code. It does not run on the browser, so while you can put `@{}` blocks inside a JavaScript `<script>` block, that code get transposed once, and only once when the view is composed into HTML and sent to the browser.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '@Url.Action("GetItem")',
    data: { inputID: sn.target.value },
    dataType: "text",
});
```

... is a JQuery ajax call to the server. The thing to remember about ajax is that it is asynchronous in nature meaning you need to think about ajax calls as  call-backs or something like "chains". A call will be posted to (or got from) the server then it needs to be set up with what to do with the response. For applications that are running against modern browsers you can also use JavaScript directly with "fetch" which is honestly a bit cleaner of an option to work with. But sticking with JQuery...

The first thing is to have your controller method package up the data you want to return. Typically this will be passed as Json where we want to pass a block of data. I do not recommend passing entities to the view as they are typically heavier than what the view will need and can lead to exceptions and problems when passed back and forth. It is advisable to create a ViewModel, which is a plain ol' C# class that contains the properties that the view will need. So for instance if we have an Item entity and we want the item's ID and Name in the view:

```
[Serializable]
public class ItemViewModel
{
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I generally go a step further with a standard `Response<T>` class which contains a Boolean IsSuccessful along with an optional string Message and a generic typed Data for parsing responses. This way you can differentiate between server errors (hard errors) and softer failures such as validation or transient failures. This way all Ajax calls pass back a standard IsSuccessful flag, where if `false` we can do something like bring up a toastr notification with the message from the server. For a simpler example the below code just returns the view model:

Then in the controller to service the Ajax call:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult GetItem(string inputId)
{
    //item is assigned single string value from db
    item = _context.Items
         .Where(x => /* condition */ )
         .Select(x => new ItemViewModel
         {
             ItemId = x.ItemId,
             Name = x.Name
         }).Single();

    return Json(item);
}
```

Note that HTTP Post calls can return data but they are intended for actions where you want to perform an action such as to modify data state. (Arguably edits would be PUT or PATCH) When requesting data this would typically be a GET, but there's nothing stopping a POST. The main difference is where/how parameters are passed. In a GET request they are passed with the URL where with a Post they are passed in the request data. JQuery and Ajax have evolved over time so there are few different ways to handle responses, and you may come across examples of each of them. The typical ones are a "success" callback and the `.done()` handler. These are where you would handle the successful response from your controller call:

using GET /w "success":

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: '@Url.Action("GetItem", new { inputId: sn.target.value })',
    success: function (data, xhr, status) {
        $('#item').val(data.itemId); // I.e. a hidden input for the item ID
        $('#item-name').val(data.name);
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        // Handle error coming back from server.
    }
});
```

... using `.done()` (recommended):

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: '@Url.Action("GetItem", new { inputId: sn.target.value })',
}).done(function (data, xhr, status) {
    $('#item').val(data.itemId); 
    $('#item-name').val(data.name);
}).fail(function(xhr, status, error) {
   // Handle error coming back from server.
});
```

In both cases you should see how the response for the call is "chained" with the callback containing the JS code to execute when the response comes back. Note that you do not want to try and put Razor (`@ {}`) code constructs into things like the callbacks. Razor constructs will be parsed only when the page is initially loaded, not when these callbacks executed. You will see examples that use Razor code blocks inside JS, however these can only serve working with initial state when the page is first rendered.

JavaScript `fetch` looks somewhat similar to the `.done()` but it's more like "Dude, where's my car" with "... and then?" where response actions are chained:

```
try {
    fetch('@Url.Action("GetItem", new { inputId: sn.target.value })').then(response => {
        if (response.ok) {
            return response.json();
        }
        throw new Error(response.statusText);
    }).then(data => {
        $('#item').val(data.itemId); 
        $('#item-name').val(data.name);
    });
} catch (ex) {
    // handle error.
}
```

One advantage of `fetch` over JQuery is that it can be set up to run asynchronously in an async method and awaited. (There are probably Promise wrappers for JQuery Ajax, but honestly that is a rabbit hole I don't like to spend much time looking down)

That should hopefully give you a bit of a start on how to tackle Ajax calls /w MVC reasonably cleanly. You can pass back things from calls other than Json, you can pass back redirect responses or even have controller methods call the view engine to render a partial view to package up and send back, such as to bring up a modal dialog or swap out a templated control. There is a lot of flexibility but it will involve a fair bit of trial & error plus sifting through an evolving documentation base.

Comment: You gave me a lot of studying to go do but helped narrow it down significantly. I will try to switch this to fetch as I prefer to avoid using an ajax call like this for something so simple. I also very much want to clean the whole project up and use the ViewModels.